# Is snprintf is safe in terms of buffer overflow?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

For example:

```
char *buffer[100];
snprintf(buffer, 512, "%s", argv[1]);
```

Is it possible to exploit it using buffer overflow?

Comment: If you use it correctly,  yes

Comment: You mean `char buffer[100]` presumably.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you define the array of 100 pointers to `char`. On 64bit systems it will be 800 bytes long and it will be big enough to accommodate the 512 characters.

> Is it possible to exploit it using buffer overflow?

Every language can be exploited if the programmer deliberately allows it, abuses it, does not know language good enough or simply is careless, and it exactly what you try to do (with no success on 64 bits systems).

Comment: <pedantic> regarding your second sentence, on a Cray XMP you would *not* have space, since like every other base type a `char` was 64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

If you use it correctly it is safe.

If you use it as shown, absolutely not safe. `512 > 100` therefore an overflow bug exists.

`snprintf` can only respect limits it is *correctly informed about*. It is your job as a C programmer to correctly match these limits.

One of the most significant challenges is ensuring that this information is consistent and, even more importantly, difficult to mess up. You should steer towards making mistakes more obvious, visually, whenever possible.

In this case:

```c
#define BUFFER_SIZE 512

char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
snprintf(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, "%s", argv[1]);
```

Comment: When the buffer is declared in the same scope where the `snprintf` appears, good practice is `snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, ... )`

Comment: It depends if you're dealing with a `char buffer[N]` or `char* buffer = malloc(N)` situation.

Comment: @user3386109: Though error-prone if you decide to replace `char buffer[SIZE];` with `char *buffer = malloc(SIZE);`

Comment: `512 > 100` The posted code is wrong in several ways, but technically an array of `100` *pointers* might have room enough for `512` *characters*, so the problem is not necessarily a buffer overrun.

Comment: @dxiv This code shouldn't compile with `char*[100]` unless YOLO mode is engaged.

Comment: @tadman True that. I'll remember *YOLO mode* for other suitable situations ;-)

Comment: `snprintf(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, "%s", argv[1]);` is a good first step toward safety, but without without checking the return value, the safety is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

The safety depends on the numbers you pass as parameters to the function.  Basically if you do what you have posted as sample, you'll run into trouble and your code will be difficult to maintain (using plain literals)  The best approach from my point of view is this:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096 /* for example */
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "format...", parameters);
```

as the buffer size number is defined in one place only, and if you change it you don't need to go variable by variable, checking that  you need to update numbers everywhere.

In your code you have declared an array of pointers to char, that you later use as a buffer of characters, use different numbers for the size of the buffer and you are mixing types that have nothing to do with each other.  In a `char[]` you store characters, while in a `char (*)[]` you store pointers to chars (this is what you have defined)